# Path not setting up for a setup

Tags: bash, environment-variables, paths, .profile

I am unable to add path of my `omnet bin directory` for the installation.

During the installation i go to the omnet directory and enter `./configure` which gives me the following errors

```
WARNING: your PATH doesn't contain /home/ABC/Desktop/omnetpp-4.1/bin!
Add the following line to your .profile or .bash_profile (provided you use bash):
export PATH=$PATH:/home/ABC/Desktop/omnetpp-4.1/bin


WARNING: The TCL_LIBRARY environment variable is not set, and without it
Tkenv (the GUI runtime environment) may be unable to find the BLT library.

Add the following line to your .profile or .bash_profile (provided you use bash):
export TCL_LIBRARY=/usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.4
```

So i do the exact thing ... go to the profile file ~/.profile and it now looks like this

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
     # include .bashrc if it exists
     if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
     . "$HOME/.bashrc"
     fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
export PATH=$PATH:/home/ABC/Desktop/omnetpp-4.1/bin
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
    export TCL_LIBRARY=/usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.4

fi
```

But still the error persists. What am i doing wrong ??

Comment: Have you logged in again, to make the changes to .profile effective?

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` say?

Comment: Why do you only set it if you have a directory named `"$HOME/bin"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have logged back in (the changes happen only when you start a new shell). Additionally, try using `.bash_profile` instead of `.profile`. To test without logging back in, you can source the file directly by typing:

```
. ~/.profile
```